# Can org automatically track what project I'm working on for me?

Tags: org-mode

Could something watch which buffer I have open and clock me in and out (of a project) based on that?

I use `projectile` which has the idea of a "project" (anything in a git repo, basically); maybe it could hook into that?

Maybe it should be a second clock. Keeping track this way would be a little more honest or accurate in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you:

```lisp
;; Initially set to 0
(setq active-projects-list nil)

(setq project-org-id-alist
      '(("/path/to/one/project/" . "89cd11b1-2871-4d5d-a19f-ace68810051d")
        ("/path/to/another/project/" . "cde4cbec-60aa-4dc4-b188-1b7522996081")))

(defun log-active-project ()
  "Logs the active project.

Add this to the `buffer-list-update-hook'.

The logging assumes that you're always working on some project.
For instance, for the purposes of this function, switching to an
``unaffiliated'' buffer (as reported by projectile) has no effect
— you will be ``clocked'' as still working on the last active
project, at least until you switch to a different project."
  (let* ((project (ignore-errors (projectile-project-root)))
         (last-logged-project (car active-projects-list))
         (org-id (cdr (assoc project project-org-id-alist)))
         (last-org-id (cdr (assoc last-logged-project project-org-id-alist))))
    (unless (or (equal last-logged-project project)
                (not org-id))
      (setq active-projects-list (cons project active-projects-list))
      (if last-org-id (org-with-point-at (org-id-find last-org-id 'marker)
                        (if (org-clock-is-active)
                            (org-clock-out))))
      (org-with-point-at (org-id-find org-id 'marker)
        (org-clock-in)))))


(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'log-active-project)
```

Surprisingly, testing with this hasn't resulted a noticeable lag when switching buffers.

It works when switching buffers (with `C-x b`), switching Emacs "windows" (e.g. `C-x o`) and even switching to a different Emacs "frame" with your window manager. However, it does not "clock" you out when you switch focus away from Emacs.

Comment: thanks so much for implementing this! I also found this https://github.com/novoid/Memacs after making this question. Not sure if I want to go that deep into though!